# How to replace multiple if-else statements to optimize code?

Tags: java, if-statement, optimization, contains

I want to know if there is any way i could optimize this code.

```
String[] array;
for(String s:array){
   if(s.contains("one"))
       //call first function
   else if(s.contains("two"))
      //call second function
   ...and so on
}
```

The string is basically lines I am reading from a file.So there can be many number of lines.And I have to look for specific keywords in those lines and call the corresponding function.

Comment: You can use Switch Case instead.. Nothing other can help you!!!

Comment: How can switch case help in this case.? I have a string line in which i am checking for substring. Its not "exact matching".

Comment: What are the functions like? Do the all have the same signature?

Comment: function is basically a symbol for the operation that i am going to perform. If the line contains the substring then i use line.substring() to extract specific information that i need.

Comment: By "optimize", do you mean that you want it to run faster? Are you having a performance problem?

Comment: If it can be made faster then great. But mostly I am looking to reduce the size of this code because I have to use muliple if-else statements.

Comment: Are you using Java 8? it may be possible to do something with lambdas

Comment: I'd use regex.  Your pattern can then be set to match as many as you want and do it all within one .matches() call.  Example regex: one|two|three

Comment: Yes, I am using Java8. Can you provide some relevant link?

Comment: @Duston the substrings can be space separated values with special characters. How would regex work there. Can you provide an example

Comment: flkes made the answer I was going to do.

Comment: is this order dependent? For example, if the string is `"this is two and one"` do you only "call first function"?

Comment: For spaces and special characters, use escape sequences.  For example: one\ two|three\ four|five will match "one two", "three four" and "five".  For other special characters, do some Googling about Regex.

Comment: just imagine the case you are getting to like
eighteen
you would Trigger ´else if(s.contains("eight"))
     
}´ and ´else if(s.contains("teighteen"))

}´

Comment: @flkes there will be not overlapping. so no not order dependent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This wont stop you code from doing many `String#contains` calls, however, it will avoid the `if/else` chaining..

You can create a key-function map and then iterate over the entries of this map to find which method to call.

```
public void one() {...}
public void two() {...}
private final Map<String, Runnable> lookup = new HashMap<String, Runnable>() {{
    put("one", this::one);
    put("two", this::two);
}};
```

You can then iterate over the entry-set:

```
for(final String s : array) {
    for(final Map.Entry<String, Runnable> entry : lookup) {
        if (s.contains(entry.getKey())) {
            entry.getValue().run();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this will certainly degrade the performance as now I will have to loop over the entire map to get the function i need to call. Thanks anyways

Comment: On second thoughts, with few manipulations this will serve my purpose.

Comment: On second thought, with a few tweaks this will server my purpose. +1 for answer

Comment: There is no reason to use a `TreeMap` here, iterating over a `HashMap` is likely to be faster, as its based on a flat array. Further, there is no reason to create an entire subclass just to save typing `lookup.` two times (or once per entry). @Anurag: this code doesn’t iterate over the entire map, it stops at the first match, so there’s no performance difference to your original `if … else if …` sequence.

Comment: @Holger in the begining I assumed the if else blocks  were order dependant- later OP said they are not. So yes i agree that hashmap would be a better choice!

Comment: Well, it would be a property of the contrived example that `"one"` is smaller than `"two"` in lexicographic order, but it would be pure luck, if the order imposed by `TreeMap` matches the program order of the original `if … else if …` statements for the actual keywords. If maintaining the lookup order is required, using a `LinkedHashMap` and putting in the desired order would be the more natural choice.

Comment: You just need to do get on the map to get the function to call. This is the correct answer

Comment: @Peter Gelderbloem: just using `get` doesn’t work as we’re not looking up a match, but a substring. So iterating over the candidates and calling `contains` is unavoidable. Or you use the regex variant of my answer to get the matching string. Then, you could use `get` on a `Map` instead of using `switch`, whatever you prefer…

Answer (score 1):

You can use switch, but in this case i think the if else is the best way

Answer (score 1):

Since you stated that the order of the checks is not important, you can use a combination of regular expression matching and `switch`:

```
static final Pattern KEYWORDS=Pattern.compile("one|two|tree|etc");
```

```
Matcher m=KEYWORDS.matcher("");
for(String s:array) {
    if(m.reset(s).find()) switch(m.group()) {
        case "one": //call first function
            break;
        case "two": //call second function
            break;
        case "three": //call third function
            break;
        case "etc": // etc
            break;
    }
}
```

Since this will stop at the first match, regardless of which keyword, it is potentially more efficient than checking one keyword after another, for strings containing a match close to the beginning.