# Compressing Similar if Statements (Java)

Tags: java

I am trying to select a certain array out of 16 depending on what value is passed into the constructor of a class. The value entered will be used in a series of if statements that will choose the array. Something like this

```
    package Model;

    import javax.swing.*;
    public class Die extends JButton{
         String letters[] = new String[6];
         public Die(int number){
               Controller con = new Controller();
               if(number==1){
                    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++}{
                        letters[i] = con.die1[i];
                    }
               }
               if(number==2){
                    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++}{
                        letters[i] = con.die2[i];
                    }
               }
               if(number==3){
                    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++}{
                        letters[i] = con.die3[i];
                    }
               }
         }
    }
```

(Keep in mind that I haven't checked this code, and I have not created all 16 if statements).
Basically I want to compress these if statements somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: using switch case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace multiple if-else statements to optimize code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110120/how-to-replace-multiple-if-else-statements-to-optimize-code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare a `Map<Integer, String[]>`  that associates the number to the String to each `die` array  and you would have not any conditional statements.

```
Controller con = new Controller();
Map<Integer, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();   
map.put(1, con.die1);
map.put(2, con.die2);
map.put(3, con.die3);


if(number>=1 && number<=3){
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++}{
        letters[i] = map.get(number)[i];
    }
}
```

And as suggested by Lino you could even move this mapping into the Controller class which makes more sense in terms of responsibility :

```
private Map<Integer, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
public Controller(){
  map.put(1, die1);
  map.put(2, die2);
  map.put(3, die3);
}
public String getLetter(int number, int index){
    map.get(number)[index];
}
```

And the `Die` client could be now :

```
Controller con = new Controller();       
if(number>=1 && number<=3){
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++}{
        letters[i] = con.getLetter(number, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: best would probably be to declare that map inside `Controller` and then expose it only via method calls

Comment: @Lino Excellent advise  in terms of design. I updated.

Comment: Would give you another upvote, but I can only push that button once ;)

Comment: How does `con.die[i]` work? According to the OP these are different arrays `con.die1`, `con.die2`, `con.die3`. Did you assume `con.die` is a 2D array?. If that is the case, then why do you need the *for* loop looping for 5 times, shouldn't it be `letters = map.get(i);`?

Comment: Actually, @user7 a 2D array would be a really good idea, I'll implement that now - thanks.

Comment: @user7  You are right. I didn't notice that this had several arrays : `con.die1`, `con.die2`. I updated to stay conform to the initial requirement.

Comment: @Sam Behm This is also a possibility. It avoids declaring several arrays variables and if the arrays may be coupled, it is not at all a bad thing.

Answer (score 4):

Best would be to select in the `if` branches only which array that should be iterated:

```
String[] array;

if(number == 1){
    array = con.die1;
} else if(number == 2){
    array = con.die2;
} else if(number == 3){
    array = con.die3;
} else {
    // throw error or select a default array
}
```

And then just iterate over the selected array afterwards outside of the `if`s:

```
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++}{
     letters[i] = array[i];
}
```

---

For future cases, it is best to analyze the code inside the if-statements.

1. What is the same everywhere?
2. What is different everywhere?

Just from these 2 points you'll see that:

1. You're always iterating over an array.
2. The array is just different everytime.

So it is quite easy to see that just extracting the logic of iterating out of the if-statements. And the selection of the array to stay inside.

Answer (score 1):

Since all loops are the same, you could move the if-statement inside the loop. In addition, you could change the if-statements to a switch, or (perhaps less readable but shorter) a nested ternary-if:

With switch:

```
Controller con = new Controller();
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
  switch(number){
    case 1:
      letters[i] = con.die1[i];
      break;
    case 2:
      letters[i] = con.die2[i];
      break;
    case 3:
      letters[i] = con.die3[i];
      break;
    ...
    default:
      // Do something if the number is unknown
      break;
  }
}
```

With ternary if:

```
Controller con = new Controller();
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
  letters[i] = number==1 ? con.die1[i]
               : number==2 ? con.die2[i]
               : number==3 ? con.die3[i]
               : ...;
}
```

A ternary if is basically a shorter variation of an `if-else` (in the form of `<condition> ? <value_if_true> : <else_value>`. Here an example of a ternary if that is perhaps better understandable:

```
int a=...;
System.out.println(a<5 ? "Less than 5" : a<15 ? "Less than 15" : "Else (15 or larger)");
```

This is basically the same as:

```
if(a<5){
  System.out.println("Less than 5");
} else if(a<15){
  System.out.println("Less than 15");
} else{
  System.out.println("Else (15 or larger)");
}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jY69DsIwDIT3PsWpUztQkYGFHzExIMHEiBgMhJIS0ioxSAjx7CGpYAABYrAs2/fduaIzdartwfuNJucwJ2WuCdCc1lpt4Jg4tHOttjiGU7Zgq0y5XIFs6fKoBJRhEEaYGpaltEVD1skwZFGz7K7yQdLqFhfH8ljUJy6a4MLaZDTsYYx0JkM078mgl6IPGoq3tWj36UQ7iSwcawsd3KXN06e72kW3x0sfw15iAhZlN8jo2cLiX1q84b@oLy@3cBLr5r0X3Ts)

As you can see, it's much less readable, so I would prefer to use longer if-statements in most cases, but with your code I would personally use a ternary if to make the code more compact without making it too complex.

Comment: Sidenote: when using ternary ifs it is recommended to use parentheses as it can get highly unreadable

Comment: @Lino Good point. Usually I use line breaks and indentations, but parenthesis are indeed a nice way as well for nested ternary-ifs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Arrays.copyOf` method from `Java API`.

```
               if(number==1){
                    letters = Arrays.copyOf(con.die1, 5); 
               }
               if(number==2){
                    letters = Arrays.copyOf(con.die2, 5); 
               }
               if(number==3){
                    letters = Arrays.copyOf(con.die3, 5); 
               }
```

Comment: According to OPs code, only the first 5 elements are copied to the letters array.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [`switch` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html):

```
String[] array;

switch (number) {
        case 1:  array = con.die1;
                 break;
        case 2:  array = con.die2;
                 break;
        [...]
        case 16: array = con.die16;
                 break;
        default: // throw error or select a default array
    }
```